# How can this contradiction be valid?

Tags: logic

((S⇔M)∧(M∧¬M)⇒(S∧¬S))

If I were to provide evidence that the premises (S⇔M) and (M∧¬M) were undeniably empirically true, then does that not mean that the conclusion (S∧¬S) MUST be true according to the rules of FOL? How can a contradiction be true? I have looked up dialetheism but due to my lack of experience using formal logic I cannot come to understand the implications. What would it mean if I proved this sentence in the real world?

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify exactly what I am asking. I hope that my query, although at a much lower level than most of the other questions, can at least be understood.

Answer (score 2):

If one of your hypotheses
(M∧¬M)
is a contradiction
(and therefoe false),
then it is not surprising
that a conclusion is 
also false.

Comment: I've cleaned up the statement to better represent what I've found. (S⇔(P∧M))∧(¬(P∨M)∧S) I have found a case in the real world where both sides of the conjunction are true, yet the truth table of this statement comes out as all false, a contradiction. I've shown my overall argument to a number of philosophy professors at my University and they have told me that my reasoning for why each side is true, is sound. So other than "it can't be true because it can't be true" what do you make of this?